# How can i render XTemplate in Container in Ext Js 4?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs4.2

I want to link XTEmplate to my Container something like :

```
var t = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
         // here somehow i render Xtemplate
        });

var tmp = new Ext.Template("<div>Hello {0}.</div>");
```